# Icons will not increase in size and change font

Tags: css, html, icons

I am very new to HTML5 and CSS. I have managed to create with the help of your site and a template a working page that looks quite good.

When I add an Icon to make the Nav more interesting ( I have added an ambulance) the Icon does not appear to enlarge even when I add the fa-fa x3  code and also changes the font to the right of the icon. When I swap the icon for the original the font returns but not the icon I wish to use. This is probably a newbie question but I do want to learn. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We're all guessing here because you haven't posted your markup, but from the small bit of code in your question there is an error anyway!

```
fa-fa x3
```

The above is incorrect, see below for the correct order.

```
fa fa-facebook fa-3x
```

Example with markup using the fa-3x

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x"></i>
```

The sizing is all explained in the [Font awesome docs.](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#larger)

Comment: Apologies, 
This shows a small ambulance 18px in height in the Nav bar area and next to it the text displays <li><a href="#contact" id="help-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="fa fa-ambulance fa-3x">Contact Us</span></a></li>
This code shows a Portfolio icon that is 39px in height and is how I would like the ambulance size to appear. .<li><a href="#portfolio" id="portfolio-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-th">Portfolio</span></a></li>`
The ambulance icon does not enlarge and also changes the text font which throws the Nav bar. Many thanks

Comment: Hi Johnny, I've put your code into a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4gtwbLe/ - could you edit your working code into this so its clearer to understand what you are wanting? It looks like your trying to add in a custom icon the same size as the ambulance - is this right?

Comment: Hi GrantB,  I have added a little of the CSS code to this file which may help. I did take a screen shot of the side Nav bar but don't appear to be able to upload. Your link above does show different fonts so this may be all you need. You are correct all I want to do is make the ambulance icon the same size as the other 5 in the Nav bar. The ambulance does increase in the main content using the -3x but doesn't have any effect in the Nav bar. Thanks Johnny (newbie!)

Comment: Johnny you need to update the jsfiddle, and re-link me so I can see.

Comment: Hi GrantB sorry for my delay. I have been trying to resolve and hopefully this will show where I am. Many thanks https://jsfiddle.net/Johnny1/20h10aez/

Answer (score 0):

you can increase font awesome icons size by using em unit in font-size

like

```
font-size: 1.5em;
```